# Paypal IPN - alternatives by competitors?

Tags: e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I've integrated PayPal's Instant Payment Notification system/kit with my site. It's been working well for years.

I'd like to add another method, as PayPal has been concerning me with their industry-leading fees and censorship efforts. I'm not saying others are much better, but I want to at least add a second-string option.

Can any of you recommend an alternative that is as easy / similar to PayPal's IPN ?

All thoughts welcome, and thanks.

Comment: IPN is several generations old, and there is no reason to use it for PayPal payments today. You should look into a current PayPal Checkout integration, which can include smart buttons for alternate payment methods that will show according to the buyer's location: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Answer (score 1):

I use Paypal IPN as my default payment for my store. I also developed an alternative at [FastPring](https://developer.fastspring.com/docs/webhooks-overview), Bitpay, CoinPayments, and Paddle. Bitpay and CoinPayments are for processing payments in cryptos. CoinPayments uses an IPN-like system. Paddle is for processing cards like Paypal. It also uses an IPN-like system thru [webhooks](https://developer.paddle.com/webhook-reference/ZG9jOjI1MzUzOTg0-webhook-reference). Fastspring uses webhooks. I created a single file that processed the webhooks I need to process. Note that Stripe also uses Webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

For my store, PayPal's IPN has been the primary payment method. However, I've explored and set up several alternatives to diversify our payment options. These include many of the same Stan listed above. Bitpay, coinpayments and poof.io

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).